# How to calculate distance between classes? and the corresponding python function?

Tags: python, statistics

I have vectors belongs to known classes, how to define the distance between classes? For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(100))
class1 = np.array([np.sin(x)*3 + np.random.rand(100) for i in range(20)])
class2 = np.array([np.cos(x)*3 + np.random.rand(100) for i in range(15)])
class3 = np.array([np.sin(x)*3 + np.random.rand(100)*1.2 for i in range(10)])

# how to define function dist so that:
dist(class1, class3) < dist(class1, class2)
```

Comment: Define what kind of distance you want and how to handle the different vector length? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what is your need ? For the moment in your example you have 3 different shapes of object: (20, 100), (15, 100) and (10, 100). It seems complicated to define any comparison between them.

Comment: I mean class 1 have 20 samples, and 15, 10 samples for class 2 and class 3. I want to define the distance between classes based on their samples.